# Specify colors in seaborn scatterplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I want the plots of seaborn to look sober, since default settings are to shinny for some use cases.

so this is the setting I have so far:

```
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.axes_style("darkgrid")
```

With this code:

[image]

I want to change the orange one, so I tried using a palete:

[image]

I want to have E.G. the these blue and green colors:

[image]

Comment: `palette = [sns.color_palette("Blues")[-1], sns.color_palette("BuGn")[0]]`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, it works